# как уменьшить время ожидания отклика устройства в сети

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, timeout, paramiko

Как уменьшить время ожидания отклика (timeout) устройства в сети, когда оно не подключено(его нет в сети), в конструкции except? Python, модуль paramico, windows7. Код:

```
try:
    ssh.connect(ipAddress, port=22, username, password)
    ....            
except TimeoutError as e:
    text.append(str(e))
```

Когда есть большой список устройств, большая половина которых не в сети, очень долго ожидать результата проверки - кто есть в сети.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/client.html
У метода `connect` есть параметр `timeout`.

```
ssh.connect(..., timeout=seconds)
```

П.С. `paramiko` пишется через `k`

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но при записи ssh.connect(ipAddress, port=22, username, password, banner_timeout=30) время ожидания почему-то совсем не изменяется. Засекал. Хоть 30, хоть 60, хоть 120с поставить. И нет сообщений об ошибках.

Comment: А зачем `banner_timeout`? Просто `timeout=5` пробовали? Я давненько не пользовал парамико, была та же проблема, решал именно уменьшением таймаута, или предварительным пингом/нмапом 22 порта.

Comment: andry, пробовал, минимальный  timeout, а также время ожидания без установки timeout - 22сек. Если  установить 21с или ниже, возникает ошибка "socket.timeout: timed out ". А пинговать не нужно по условию(